# Getting Error: Command 'idevice_id -l' while running the appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I get this error while running appium and don't know how to resolve it:

```
[XCUITest] Error: Command 'idevice_id -l' errored out: Error: spawn idevice_id ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:32:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:213:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Code please mate?

Comment: HI arunkumar, could you describe what code you are running which returns this error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the udid capability resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

`idevice_id` is part of `libimobiledevice`. You can probably install it with `brew install libimobiledevice` (right now I also recommend the --HEAD tag if you are using iOS10 devices), or from https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice